# Best way to traverse an unordered map and why?

Tags: c++, stl, iteration, unordered-map

[Leetcode medium- single number II](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-ii/)

I was solving this question and had the concept charted out well on paper. The problem was though, with the iteration.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        unordered_map<int,int> hash;
        for (int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
            hash[nums[i]]++;
        }
        int x;
        for (auto i:hash){
            if (i.second==1){
                x=i.first;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
};
```

The above code solved the question perfectly. But, my initial code got a TLE error (Time Limit Exceeded)

```
class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        unordered_map<int,int> hash;
        for (int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
            hash[nums[i]]++;
        }
        int x;
        for (int i=0; i<hash.size(); i++){
            if (hash[i]==1){
                x= i;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
};
```

Here, I have iterated an unordered map in two different ways, both of which ran perfect for the base case. But otherwise, the first code passes while the second goes haywire. This brings me to my two questions-

1. What is wrong with the code? Is it not optimised, or am I doing something incorrect with syntax?
2. Is there a "correct" way to iterate unordered maps? and maybe I did it the second time?

Comment: Those aren't equivalent solutions regardless. `hash[i]` in the second code performs a hash-calc lookup (and potential insertions) in the container for values in 0..(hash.size()-1). Unless every value in that range is *already* in the container, that is an infinite loop, so the TLE isn't surprising. The first loop just enumerates the pairs in the data structure. Not only is the first one better, it is actually correct; the second is neither. It's just flat-wrong. And fyi, the first would be even better if it enumerated by `auto const&` rather than `auto`.

Comment: The first one. The second will insert elements for otherwise non-existing keys. Think about a case like the map contains the single key `1`, try to explain what will then happen to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude exactly. The ensuing incrementing of the container size due to insertion, thereby never satisfying the `i<hash.size()` is a subtle, but horrifying, result.

Comment: This is why using `LeetCode` to learn C++ is a waste of time.  If you're going to use `std::unordered_map`, one of the basics you should have realized is that `[]` inserts an item if the key cannot be found.  You learn this by reading good, peer-reviewed C++ books and materials.  LeetCode is for *experienced* programmers who want to solve random puzzle questions -- that experience includes knowing how to use the computer language you will be using to solve the problem.

Comment: `at` does not insert a new element. It throws an exception instead. Probably just as bad an outcome in your use case so I'm not sure why I brought it up.

Comment: @user4581301 It's the heat (predicted 36 deg next week here).

Comment: @Paul Low 30s here. I have a cooler running 24/7 fighting like mad to regulate my fish tank. Last year's heat dome was a real eye-opener.

Comment: Those aren't solutions at all since `unordered_map` uses linear space but the question requires constant space.

Comment: BTW there is better solution with `O(1)` memory complexity  and `O(n)` time complexity. Hint: Just count bits for specific power of 2.

Comment: @MarekR Counting bits for each power of 2 is O(n log n). You have to count bits for all powers of 2 at the same time (modulo 3 is enough so you only need 3 variables).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow you misunderstood me. It is possible to create accumulator which will cancel out any value which will appear tree times and outcome will be the only number which appeared only once. I was able to get 7ms result with that approach. It is just 4 int variables and couple crafty bit-wise operation do the trick.

Comment: @MarekR Then you did all bits in parallel as required. A lot of people make a loop for each bit saying "32 is a const so it doesn't count". But as n grows that 32 needs to become 64, then 128 and then you run out of integer types on real machines. But it should be clear by then that it's not a constant.

Answer (score 3):

The key saved to the `hash` need not be in the range from `0` to `hash.size()`.

When `hash[i]` is calculated with non-existent key `i`, this results in adding another entry to `hash` and increase `hash.size()`.

Therefore, depending on the maximum value of the keys, the second loop will run too many times.

Here is a simple example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> hash;
    hash[1] = 1;
    hash[10] = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "i = " << i << ", hash.size() = " << hash.size() << '\n';
        if (hash[i] == 1) {
            std::cout << "hash[i] == 1\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6niHTtIE20NbZZfd):

```
i = 0, hash.size() = 2
i = 1, hash.size() = 3
hash[i] == 1
i = 2, hash.size() = 3
i = 3, hash.size() = 4
i = 4, hash.size() = 5
i = 5, hash.size() = 6
i = 6, hash.size() = 7
i = 7, hash.size() = 8
i = 8, hash.size() = 9
i = 9, hash.size() = 10
i = 10, hash.size() = 11
```

You can see `hash.size()` is growing after trying non-existent keys.

Answer (score 0):

In general iterators are always going to be faster than `operator[]`, stepping though any container will be faster (or at least not slower for `std::vector`) than accessing it at random.

`unordered_map`'s `operator[]` has to calculate the hash of it's parameter then check the items matching that hash for equality. As pointed out by @Someprogrammerdude you also have the problem that if the Key doesn't exist then `operator[]` will insert a new element into the map, this will result in the map containing every key between 0 and the largest key (which kind of defeats the object of using `unordered_map` in the first place).

The iterator simply steps through every item in the container without having to do any hash calculations or equality comparisons.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, I was right, see the example in MikeCAT's answer, the code stops when it reaches the largest key

Answer (score 0):

### Hint for better solution

There is a better way to do it without `std::unordered_map` or any container. You should exploit fact that result is shown only once and any other umber appears always three times.

It is possible to create accumulator which will cancel out any value which appears 3 times and leave only single item which appeared exactly once.

I was able to pass this on leetcode with time 7ms (I reached limit of time resolution on leetcode). In my code there are only 4 `int` variables and couple crafty bit-wise operations on them.

For know I will not post solution to not spoil fun to finding this solution.

> https://godbolt.org/z/8s1jeGs48

### About iterating over `std::unorered_map`

There is no room to do significant improvement in your code to use of this container. You can add just early termination of a loop and reference:

```cpp
        for (const auto& i:hash){
            if (i.second==1){
                return i.first;
            }
        }
        return 0;
```

With your current approach, literally you can't do anything to make it significantly faster.

In your second approach you are not iterating over items of `hash` you are in fact adding new entries if the do not exists with key `i` and zero value.